# Is it possible to modify a list that exists outside of the scope of a function?

Tags: python

So, I am trying to modify a (global?) list within a function.  However, the list exists outside the scope of the function so when I call the function it doesn't actually modify the list.  I have tried using the 'global' keyword, and have tried making a copy of the existing list and then modifying that, but nothing is working.  Any suggestions?  This is python by the way.

Comment: Just pass the list into the function as a parameter?  Use a class and make the list a class variable?

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable, pass them in and have at it.

```
def list_modifier(passed_list):
    for i in range(len(passed_list)):
        passed_list[i] += 1
test_list = [5, 6, 7]
print(test_list)  # [5, 6, 7]
list_modifier(test_list)
print(test_list)  # [6, 7, 8]
```